# How to print multiple squares of star pattern in C?

Tags: c

I would like to print the below pattern, where user enters n and m (4 and 6) the outside should be stars and inside should be filled with rounds.

```
******    ******    ******    ******    
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
******    ******    ******    ******    

******    ******    ******    ******    
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
******    ******    ******    ******    

******    ******    ******    ******    
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
******    ******    ******    ******    

******    ******    ******    ******    
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
******    ******    ******    ******    

******    ******    ******    ******    
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
******    ******    ******    ******

******    ******    ******    ******    
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
******    ******    ******    ******
```

I am only able to print this using this code. What I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
int n,i,j,k,m,n1;
printf("enter table size and enter square size");
scanf("%d %d", &n, &n1);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n1; j++) 
    {
        for ( k = 0; k < n; k++) 
        {
            for ( m = 0; m < n1; m++) 
            {
                {
            if(i==0 || i==n-1)
                {
            printf("*");
                }
            else if(j==0 || j==n-1)
                {
            printf("*");
                }
            else
                {
            printf("o"); 
                }
                }
            }
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What are you stuck on? Have a specific question?

Comment: I think, mitt634, you're stuck in the output. You can't print just one square, and then print others like you want. You have to print first line, then the 2nd and so on.

Comment: What do you exactly mean? *"like 6 squares of stars if the user enters n = 3."*  (Seems that doesn't match with 9 printed squares "3x3")

Comment: This is an [exact duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659208/how-to-print-this-star-pattern-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int side;

    printf("Enter side\n");
    scanf("%d",&side);
    for(int m=0;m<side;m++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<side;j++)
        {
            for(i=0;i<side;i++)
            {
                for(int k=0;k<side;k++)
                    printf("*");
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm and it't logic is very simple.
If you include these for-loop in proper order `row{height{length{column{...}}}}`, you'll get needed result:

1. It will print `*` `length` times, then 'space'. And repeat it `column` times.
2. Then it'll move to the next line and do the same `height` times. After that, it will print a new-line character `\n`.
3. The program will repeat steps 1 (for `column` times) and 2 (for `height` times) for `row` times.

***But*** if you want to print something a bit different, you're free to change this algorithm like you want. Rename all variables to `number` and run it -- you'll get `number`x`number` squares with sides equal to `number`. Or rename `row` and `column` to `side` and run it -- you'll get a table `side`x`side` of squares with sides `height` and `length`. And so on...

I can suggest you the following algorithm that will print various squares.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    int row, column, height, length;
    int i,j,k,m;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &row, &column, &height, &length);

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            for ( k = 0; k < column; k++) {
                for ( m = 0; m < length; m++) {
                    printf("*");
                }
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
/* OUTPUT:
2  // rows
4  // columns
3  // height
5  // length
***** ***** ***** *****
***** ***** ***** *****
***** ***** ***** *****

***** ***** ***** *****
***** ***** ***** *****
***** ***** ***** *****
*/
```