# How to print this star pattern in C?

Tags: c

I would like to print the below pattern, where user enters n and m (4 and 6) the outside boundary should be made up with stars and inside should be filled with circles.

```
******    ******    ******    ******    
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
******    ******    ******    ******    

******    ******    ******    ******    
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
******    ******    ******    ******    

******    ******    ******    ******    
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
******    ******    ******    ******    

******    ******    ******    ******    
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
*oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*    *oooo*
******    ******    ******    ******
```

The code I have written is as below. What I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n,i,j,k,m,n1;
    printf("enter table size and enter square size");
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &n1);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n1; j++) 
        {
            for ( k = 0; k < n; k++) 
            {
                for ( m = 0; m < n1; m++) 
                {
                    {
                        if(i==0 || i==n-1)
                        {
                            printf("*");
                        }
                        else if(j==0 || j==n-1)
                        {
                            printf("*");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("o"); 
                        }
                    }
                }
                printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for showing efforts,and coming up with readable code.

Comment: What does your code currently do?

Comment: 1( This needs a third parameter that indicates how many blocks to print 2) there seems to be some confusion as to which parameter is the width of each block and which parameter is the height of each block.  3) the variable names 'n' and 'n1' give no indication of what the variable will be used for.

Comment: there is an unnecessary set of braces around the portion of the code that contains the print statements

Comment: the return value from the call to scanf() needs to be checked (for = 2 in this case) to assure that both parameters were entered.

Comment: What all depens on `m` and `n`? Can you please discribe what is affactet from the input n and m!

Comment: I have now done the changes to my code and got the required output. Thanks a ton for pointing out my mistake. You are the best.

Answer (score 1):

The corrected code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n,i,j,k,m,n1;
    printf("enter table size and enter square size");
scanf("%d %d", &n, &n1);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n1; j++) 
    {
        for ( k = 0; k < n; k++) 
        {
            for ( m = 0; m < n1; m++) 
            {
                {
                    if(j==0 || j==n1-1)
                    {
                        printf("*");
                    }
                    else if(m==0 || m==n1-1)
                    {
                        printf("*");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("o"); 
                    }
                }
            }
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Your index variables does the following:

```
    |----------------n----------------------|
    |--m--|
-   *******  ******* ******* ******* *******
|   *o ...
|   *o ...
j   *o ...
|
|
-
```

So basically you must print * when j is in first row or last row of each square or when m is in first row or last row of the square (n1).

Hope this helps

Comment: You have answered my question very accurately. I can't thank you enough for that.